# Push data into array with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I need to generate an array like this:

```
$person = array(
    array(
        "name" => "brian",
        "age" => "25"
    ),
    array(
         "name" => "simon",
         "age" => "21"
    )
);
```

I put this code into a simple for loop:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $new_array = array("name"=>'Brian', "age"=>'25');
    array_push($person, $new_array);
}
```

If the for loop must be repeated 10 times I should have 10 rows with Brian name and age 25 but I have this result:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) [value] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) [0] => 0 [key] => 0 )
```

Am I doing something wrong with the array_push?
Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://3v4l.org/XZGOF

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create `$new_array = array();`

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $new_array[] = array("name"=>'Brian', "age"=>'25');   
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Out put will be

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [name] => Brian [age] => 25 ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your people as single arrays, `array_push` could be interesting for you because it allows you to push multiple arrays in one step:

```
$brian = array(
                "name" => "brian",
                "age" => "25"
        );
$simon = array(
        "name" => "simon",
        "age" => "21"
);

$persons = [];
array_push($persons, $brian, $simon);
```