# how to create array with associative array in other array php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I´m trying to create this structure to send data to `API`

```
$metaDataList = [
            [        
                "key" => "item_description0",
                "value" => "DCALUXE",
            ]
        ];
```

i need this structure.

I´m trying to do this:

```
$items_selected = [];
        for($i=0; $i<count($precontractData->items);$i++){
            $items_selected["item_description$i"] = $precontractData->items[$i]->name;
            $items_selected["item_quantity$i"] = intval($precontractData->items[$i]->cuantity);
        }
        array_push($metaDataList, $items_selected);
```

but my result it´s not equal to my needed structure. I try with merge array, i try with array_map, but i don´t know how i can to do one array with this structure. in key "key" should be `"item_description$i"` and in value should be `$precontractData->items[$i]->name`

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Can you show final structure you need for 2 items?

Comment: Related: [Push data into array with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45168714/2943403)

Comment: A relevant insight: ["_The main use of array_push() is that you can push multiple values onto the end of the array._"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2431653/2943403) and ["_You can add more than 1 element in one shot to array using array_push_"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14233054/2943403)

Comment: @scorpions Implementation of `array_push()` in a loop: https://3v4l.org/dooRo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing your array wrongly. There is no keys named `item_description_0`, just `key` and `value`. So you need to adjust your loop:

```php
$metaDataList = [];

foreach ($precontractData->items as $i => $item) {
    $metaDataList[] = [
        'key' => "item_description{$i}",
        'value' => $item->name,
    ];
    $metaDataList[] = [
        'key' => "item_quantity{$i}",
        'value' => intval($item->cuantity),
    ];
}
```

Final `$metaDataList` will be similar to

```
[
    [
        'key' => 'item_description0',
        'value' => 'Name',
    ],
    [
        'key' => 'item_quantity0',
        'value' => 100,
    ],
    [
        'key' => 'item_description1',
        'value' => 'Name 1',
    ],
    [
        'key' => 'item_quantity1',
        'value' => 101,
    ],
];
```